# AppBarLayout leaves previous expanded view spacing after fragment change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I  have the following layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nl.psdcompany.duonavigationdrawer.views.DuoDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScaleOpen="0.87"
    app:marginFactor="0.7">

    <nl.psdcompany.duonavigationdrawer.views.DuoMenuView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="@string/tag_menu"
        app:footer="@layout/drawer_footer"
        app:header="@layout/drawer_header" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="@string/tag_content"
        android:translationZ="8dp">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</nl.psdcompany.duonavigationdrawer.views.DuoDrawerLayout>
```

The include layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:translationZ="4dp"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:scrimAnimationDuration="250">
        <!--
            Toolbar Collapsing Layout
        -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_title"
                fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_black"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_secondary_title"
                fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_regular"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_medium">
                <!--
                    Toolbar TOP Layout
                -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/default_toolbar_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <!-- Starting icons container -->
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_icon_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_hamburger"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:tint="@color/white"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_burger_menu_white" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_start_icon"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_button_white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_start_text_icon"
                                fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_bold"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Cancel"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_button_white" />

                        </FrameLayout>
                        <!-- Step Progress Bar -->
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toolbar_left_icon_container"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                        <!-- Main title centered in the toolbar -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_title"
                                fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_black"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:text="View Offer"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_secondary_title"
                                fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_regular"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                                android:text="last visit on 15-03"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!-- Secondary end icon -->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_secondary_end_icon"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_end_icon_container"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white" />

                        <!-- Primary end icon container-->
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_end_icon_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_primary_end_icon"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white" />

                            <!-- Badge counter container -->
                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_badge_counter_container"
                                android:layout_width="28dp"
                                android:layout_height="28dp"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_badge_icon"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:padding="4dp"
                                    android:visibility="gone"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bell_notifications" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_badge_counter"
                                    fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_medium"
                                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="3"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="9sp"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_text_icon"
                                fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_bold"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                        </FrameLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/change_postal_code_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_end_icon_container"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_background_blue"
                            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_small"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_navigation_white"
                            android:minHeight="0dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_small_medium"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_small_medium"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                            android:text="1234 AA, Amsterdam"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <!--
                    Toolbar BOTTOM Layout
                -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top_container"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom_title"
                        fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:text="View Offer"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom_secondary_title"
                        fontPath="@string/font_sf_ui_display_regular"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                        android:text="last visit on 15-04"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
                        layout="@layout/layout_search_offers" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

It consists of an AppBarLayout with an CollapsingToolbarLayout which has as the first child a Linear that's acting as the collapse layout and a Toolbar layout which holds the top bar and a static bottom one when I need a bottom non collapsing toolbar.

The collapsing works great, I can set my ToolBar to have only the top layout or only the bottom but when I change the visibility of items to Gone the AppBarLayout(or the CollapsingToolbarLayout) doesn't resize and keeps the spacing.

Example image :
[image]

After fragment change (I set views to Gone to reset the layouts)

[image]

Thank you for your time;

Comment: DID u find any solution ?

Comment: No I did not, I tried everything from removing-inflating my extra views to various settings in the layouts. 


The only thing seemed to work was to wrap my Toolbar with a frame layout which made it lose it's property to pin but resized properly to views being made GONE.

I thing the best solution is to use a nested ScrollView as a container for your activity, or every time you use a Toolbar inflate it again after changing a fragment instead of having a ToolbarManager class to manipulate it.